# When should I consider implementing a Service in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new to Grails and web development. I started doing a project on Schedule management website stuff. I came across the `Service` concept that is provided by Grails. I understood the concept, but still I have confusion on when to use services.

For example, I need to implement a `search` module, where the `manager` can search for a `user` to find his `schedules`. In this case it will be good to implement it as a controller or as a service?

So,

- When and where should I use `Service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What and where I should use `Service`?

When you want your controller do to something that may be reused by other controllers
In our application we're doing a functional separation of service. We have a CorePersistanceService, which provides method to create, delete, update and manipulate Core Domain Classes (core for us).

I think persistance services are a good way to reuse GORM code throughout Grails code. You can create method in domain classes, but I don't like that, it's way less maintanable I think

We have a PDFService class for our PDF creation, a SolrService which connect to Solr, a Statisticservice that gather all our methods which collects statictics on our datas

Services in Grails are a manner to gather methods around a particular functional theme, in order to give possibility to reuse them in controllers (I forgot to mention our SecurityService, which is a pretty good Cross-Applications Example)

Comment: It's also a convenient way to get transactions without any configuration, but with the option to easily override the default behavior with @Transactional annotations

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Right ! And it's an easy way to share code between controllers and jobs when you work with Quartz Plugin (BTW, Burt, thanks for the SpringSecurity plugin :-) )

Comment: Another thing services are good for is application configuration (things you want to change about your application depending on where/who it has been distributed to, but don't want to create a domain class for), since services are singletons by default.

Comment: @Grooveek - Another plugin that services work well for is the RabbitMQ plugin. Having a service to publish to or consume from a queue is great, since it keeps your application all together  and makes scaling as easy as spinning up another Grails instance.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Grooveek's answer;

It is also nice to use Services to keep your Controllers nice and clean.

So Views just render data to the screen, Domain objects store state, Controllers route the user around the application, and Services perform the work.

Comment: This is perhaps the _best_ use for services, since you want to keep your controllers as thin as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on an answer or vote up so I have to provide an answer that really should be a comment.  Anyways...

+1 on @tim_yates answer. Gotta love thin controllers.  2 things that I would add to the description of a controller:

1. Would be to translate parameters from the browser before hitting a service (e.g. Date, number, etc.)
2. Would be to translate data returned from services into something consumable for the views.

For me, ideally, services would never deal with translating a String parameter to it's inherent type.  Or deal with building a model to be displayed on a view.

Comment: Things a service should not have to deal with is a good answer to this question as far as I'm concerned. The idea that a service should deal with domain objects and other data, irrespective of what a Controller might do with it, is a good point to keep in mind.